# CORS giving issues once I went from localhost --> heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, axios

I have a chat application where my client side is written in Reactjs and my backend is written in Nodejs/Express. I have required cors and everything on my backend and the entire application worked perfectly when I was using localhost:3000 for the client and localhost:5000 for the server. I then deployed the server to heroku and the client to netlify, and now I am getting this CORS error every time I try to log in using a POST request (using axios as well):

[image]

Under the network tab on chrome, I get two things, a "signin" that has 204 and it works, and then a "signin" that just says error.

This is what my backend looks like in Nodejs/express:

```
require('dotenv').config()

const http = require('http');

const cors = require('cors');
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const express = require('express');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const {AddUser, FindUser, RemoveUser, FindId} = require('./users.js')


var corsOptions = {
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'https://easytalkchat.netlify.app'],
    credentials: true,
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS', 'PUT', 'DELETE'] };
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(express.json())

app.use(cookieParser());

//Tells the server what port to listen to and can add a function to talk to command line
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server is up!");
});
```

What I THINK might be the problem is maybe I'm not setting up the server using https, because I'm doing it with http. Maybe this is causing the problem but I don't know how to fix it. Other people have also mentioned it might not be a problem with CORS but rather Heroku, since Heroku only installs devDependencies or something like that, but I don't know how to fix that either.
I've tried adding headers, credentials, everything, I have no clue.

My front end looks like this:

```
const signIn = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post('https://easytalkchatapp.herokuapp.com/signin', {
      username: username,
      password: password
    }).then(res => {
...
```

and I have `axios.defaults.withCredentials = true` written at the top.

And just to re-state above, if I literally go to terminal and just run my server on localhost:5000 instead of heroku and make all my POST/GET requests through the localhost:500 server it works completely fine. If, however, I run my client on localhost:3000 and have the server be heroku, it breaks, so the problem is most certaintly with heroku and how I'm using it.

Answer (score 1):

Since, you are using withCredentials, so I thinks its better to provide specific values for origin instead of true or '*' because it will not work with credentials true.

Try using this options:

```
var corsOptions = {
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'https://easytalkchat.netlify.app'],
    credentials: true,
};
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, but I really appreciate your response. I'm still getting the same errors. I think origin: true is fine, since if I run my server from localhost:5000 and not heroku, the origin: true works.

Answer (score 1):

if you use `withCredentials= true` and when you run frontend and backend both form localhost, it runs perfectly because they are in the same origin

but if you run frontend and backend from different origin(host) in that time it gives you cors issue. for resolve this issue you have to whitelist the frontend origin in the backend

```
var corsOptions = {
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'https://easytalkchat.netlify.app'],
    credentials: true,
};
```

by this way backend now trust the frontend origin

Comment: I tried this but I am still getting the same error :( Thank you for the response though

Comment: I just check your site and there is no error occurred. works ok

Comment: Were you able to login and signup?  It won't let me.

Comment: signup isn't completed but if I use the same data twice it gives me that I am already signup. so according to that, you have some backend issue. after completing the signup you aren't sending any response. Please check your code again

Comment: What's weird is that I am sending a response and it does work totally fine on localhost, so I don't think it is a backend issue

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it was completely my own fault with my backend code. I was using process.env.(variable) and I had never specified it in the heroku config vars so it kept breaking when trying to access it. UGH. Thanks everyone.

Comment: I've ran into this problem 2 if not 3 separate times now, end up searching all these related threads, trying all these different things with CORS, and it has ended up being an environmental variable issue each time!

One time it was that I put ACCESS_ID when it was supposed to be ACCESS_SID (or vice versa).  One time I simply forgot to add the new environmental variables that I added locally because of new features I had added. 

Anyway, just a reminder to check and double-check your environmental variables, anyone reading this!